# Getting text between class in tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm learning beuatifulSoup on python and I can't understand why my code is not working. 
I'm trying to get a text "my mood" in this part of HTML code:

```
<div class="page_block_header_inner _header_inner"><a class="ui_crumb" 
 href="/lovely_detka_tytyty" onclick="return nav.go(this, event, {back: 
 true});">my mood</a><div class="ui_crumb_sep"></div><a class="ui_crumb" 
 href="/albums-68872445" onclick="return nav.go(this, event, {back: true});
```

My code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
url = 'https://vk.com/photo-68872445_422126739?rev=1'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')


for row in soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "ui_crumb"}):
    print (row.text)
```

But my code not working, I am receiving a blank string. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following class selector

```
print(soup.select_one('.group_link').text)
```

`requests` seems to hang so alternatively use `selenium`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://vk.com/photo-68872445_422126739'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
item =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".group_link"))).text
print(item)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The text you are trying to get is on an anchor tag and you are doing a find for div tag.

```
<a class="ui_crumb" href="/lovely_detka_tytyty" onclick="return nav.go(this, event, {back: true});">my mood</a>
```

is what you are trying to find so

```
for row in soup.find_all('a', class_="ui_crumb")
```

would likely work better.

Additionally, defining headers in your request will ensure the version of the page you are expecting gets returned while with no headers the server may return a page you are not expecting.

For some versions of this page the actual tag you are looking for is:

```
<a href="/lovely_detka_tytyty">my mood</a>
```

which you are more likely to find with

```
for row in soup.find_all('a', href=True, class_=False):
    print(row.get_text())
```